# turn int echo milliseconds to minuets and seconds

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `php` query that is getting a field from my database that contains an int, for example 7800. I know that 7800 is 7.7 seconds or 0.13 minutes.

I need a way to display this as `00:00:08` (rounded up)

The table print out looks like this:

```
<td><?= $row["timeSpent"] ?></td>
```

It prints out `7800`

I need `00:00:08` (H,M,S)

It's kept as an `int` in the database, not `datetime`

I have tried:

```
    <td><? echo gmdate("H:i:s",  $row['timeSpent']); ?></td>
```

Except `7.8` seconds prints as `02:10:00`

Comment: use round() function

Comment: easy enouth, yes. but im asking how to turn the int echo into (00:00:08) not how to round the 7.8 to 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use the [divide and modulo operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) to build your variables, and [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) to populate your string bits with leading zeros :

```
<?php 

function convertToTime($time) {
    $time = round($time/1000);
    $hours = floor($time/3600);
    $time = $time%3600;
    $minutes = floor($time/60);
    $seconds = $time%60;
    return str_pad($hours, 2, '0',STR_PAD_LEFT) . ':' . str_pad($minutes, 2, '0',STR_PAD_LEFT) . ':' . str_pad($seconds, 2, '0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

var_dump(convertToTime(7800)); // string '00:00:08' (length=8)
var_dump(convertToTime(60000)); // string '00:01:00' (length=8)
var_dump(convertToTime(3600000)); // string '01:00:00' (length=8)
var_dump(convertToTime(42687000)); // string '11:51:27' (length=8)

?>
```

Comment: Hmm, nice answer. this looks promising. where would I fit my table row 'timeSpent' into this ?

Comment: You'd have to declare the `convertToTime` function and then use it on your `$row` variable, with something like `<td><?= convertToTime($row["timeSpent"]); ?></td>`

Comment: thanks ill get this working then accept you answer +1 for explenation

Comment: Also, please try to usually refrain from using PHP's short opening tag `<?`, as it isn't supported by every version of PHP if the short_open_tag ini isn't set, but use `<?php` instead. Same goes for the `<?=` tag instead of `<?php echo`. More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php).

Comment: Top tip, did not know that +1